# Convert nested json to flat json in Jolt

Tags: json, nested, transformation, jolt

I am trying to transform the below input json

```json
[
  {
    "orderId": "123456",
    "orderName": "ABC12345",
    "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
    "grandTotal": 484.95,
    "shipments": [
      {
        "trackingNumber": "123456789",
        "carrierPartyId": "EXAMPLE",
        "shipmentItems": [
          {
            "orderId": "123456",
            "orderName": "ABC12345",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1009",
            "facilityExternalId": "1009",
            "productId": "101"
          },
          {
            "orderId": "123456",
            "orderName": "ABC12345",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1009",
            "facilityExternalId": "1009",
            "productId": "102"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "trackingNumber": "12345897",
        "carrierPartyId": "EXAMPLE",
        "shipmentItems": [
          {
            "orderId": "123456",
            "orderName": "ABC12345",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1003",
            "facilityExternalId": "1003",
            "productId": "103"
          },
          {
            "orderId": "123456",
            "orderName": "ABC12345",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1003",
            "facilityExternalId": "1003",
            "productId": "104"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderId": "123457",
    "orderName": "ABC12346",
    "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
    "grandTotal": 657.95,
    "shipments": [
      {
        "trackingNumber": "987654321",
        "carrierPartyId": "EXAMPLE",
        "shipmentItems": [
          {
            "orderId": "123457",
            "orderName": "ABC12346",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1007",
            "facilityExternalId": "1007",
            "productId": "105"
          },
          {
            "orderId": "123457",
            "orderName": "ABC12346",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1007",
            "facilityExternalId": "1007",
            "productId": "106"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "trackingNumber": "68435896",
        "carrierPartyId": "EXAMPLE",
        "shipmentItems": [
          {
            "orderId": "123457",
            "orderName": "ABC12346",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1008",
            "facilityExternalId": "1008",
            "productId": "107"
          },
          {
            "orderId": "123457",
            "orderName": "ABC12346",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1008",
            "facilityExternalId": "1008",
            "productId": "108"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is the desired output:

```json
[
  {
    "orderId": "123456",
    "orderName": "ABC12345",
    "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
    "grandTotal": 484.95,
    "Items": [
      {
        "facilityId": "1009",
        "facilityExternalId": "1009",
        "productId": "101"
      },
      {
        "facilityId": "1009",
        "facilityExternalId": "1009",
        "productId": "102"
      },
      {
        "facilityId": "1003",
        "facilityExternalId": "1003",
        "productId": "103"
      },
      {
        "facilityId": "1003",
        "facilityExternalId": "1003",
        "productId": "104"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderId": "123457",
    "orderName": "ABC12346",
    "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
    "grandTotal": 657.95,
    "Items": [
      {
        "facilityId": "1007",
        "facilityExternalId": "1007",
        "productId": "105"
      },
      {
        "facilityId": "1007",
        "facilityExternalId": "1007",
        "productId": "106"
      },
      {
        "facilityId": "1008",
        "facilityExternalId": "1008",
        "productId": "107"
      },
      {
        "facilityId": "1008",
        "facilityExternalId": "1008",
        "productId": "108"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

NOTE: Here there is an order map, that has a shipments list, and inside that are shipmentItems.

I want the order details and then the Items List that contains the ShipmentItems details.

I have tried some specs on the original larger json but it seems to group the Items as per the shipments and does not give the desired output.

Can anybody help me understand how can we achieve the desired output?

Thanks in advance!

**Part 2:**

Here is another scenario:

Input JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "orderId": "123456",
    "orderName": "ABC12345",
    "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
    "grandTotal": 484.95,
    "shipments": [
      {
        "trackingNumber": "123456789",
        "carrierPartyId": "EXAMPLE",
        "shipmentItems": [
          {
            "orderId": "123456",
            "orderName": "ABC12345",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1009",
            "facilityExternalId": "1009",
            "productId": "101",
            "Identifications": [
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "A",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "101",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "12",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "B",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "101",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "13",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "C",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "101",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "14",
                "thruDate": null
              },
             {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "D",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "101",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "15",
                "thruDate": null
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "orderId": "123456",
            "orderName": "ABC12345",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1009",
            "facilityExternalId": "1009",
            "productId": "102",
            "Identifications": [
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "A",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "102",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "122",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "B",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "102",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "13",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "C",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "102",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "14",
                "thruDate": null
              },
             {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "D",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "102",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "15",
                "thruDate": null
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "trackingNumber": "12345897",
        "carrierPartyId": "EXAMPLE",
        "shipmentItems": [
          {
            "orderId": "123456",
            "orderName": "ABC12345",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1003",
            "facilityExternalId": "1003",
            "productId": "103",
            "Identifications": [
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "A",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "103",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "132",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "B",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "103",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "13",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "C",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "103",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "14",
                "thruDate": null
              },
             {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "D",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "103",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "15",
                "thruDate": null
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "orderId": "123456",
            "orderName": "ABC12345",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1003",
            "facilityExternalId": "1003",
            "productId": "104",
            "Identifications": [
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "A",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "104",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "124",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "B",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "104",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "13",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "C",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "104",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "14",
                "thruDate": null
              },
             {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "D",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "104",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "15",
                "thruDate": null
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderId": "123457",
    "orderName": "ABC12346",
    "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
    "grandTotal": 657.95,
    "shipments": [
      {
        "trackingNumber": "987654321",
        "carrierPartyId": "EXAMPLE",
        "shipmentItems": [
          {
            "orderId": "123457",
            "orderName": "ABC12346",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1007",
            "facilityExternalId": "1007",
            "productId": "105",
            "Identifications": [
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "A",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "105",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "126",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "B",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "105",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "13",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "C",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "105",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "14",
                "thruDate": null
              },
             {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "D",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "105",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "15",
                "thruDate": null
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "orderId": "123457",
            "orderName": "ABC12346",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1007",
            "facilityExternalId": "1007",
            "productId": "106",
            "Identifications": [
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "A",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "106",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "162",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "B",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "106",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "13",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "C",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "106",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "14",
                "thruDate": null
              },
             {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "D",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "106",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "15",
                "thruDate": null
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "trackingNumber": "68435896",
        "carrierPartyId": "EXAMPLE",
        "shipmentItems": [
          {
            "orderId": "123457",
            "orderName": "ABC12346",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1008",
            "facilityExternalId": "1008",
            "productId": "107",
            "Identifications": [
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "A",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "107",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "165",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "B",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "107",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "13",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "C",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "107",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "14",
                "thruDate": null
              },
             {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "D",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "107",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "15",
                "thruDate": null
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "orderId": "123457",
            "orderName": "ABC12346",
            "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
            "facilityId": "1008",
            "facilityExternalId": "1008",
            "productId": "108",
            "Identifications": [
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "A",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "108",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "129",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "B",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "108",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "13",
                "thruDate": null
              },
              {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "C",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "108",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "14",
                "thruDate": null
              },
             {
                "IdentificationTypeId": "D",
                "lastUpdatedStamp": "2023-03-14T10:11:24-04:00",
                "productId": "108",
                "fromDate": "2023-02-22T15:32:23-05:00",
                "idValue": "15",
                "thruDate": null
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Desired Output:

```json
[
  {
    "grandTotal": 484.95,
    "orderId": "123456",
    "orderName": "ABC12345",
    "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
    "Items": [
      {
        "facilityId": "1009",
        "facilityExternalId": "1009",
        "productId": "101",
        "identificationValue": "15"
      },
      {
        "facilityId": "1009",
        "facilityExternalId": "1009",
        "productId": "102",
        "identificationValue": "122"
      },
      {
        "facilityId": "1003",
        "facilityExternalId": "1003",
        "productId": "103",
        "identificationValue": "132"
      },
      {
        "facilityId": "1003",
        "facilityExternalId": "1003",
        "productId": "104",
        "identificationValue": "124"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "grandTotal": 657.95,
    "orderId": "123457",
    "orderName": "ABC12346",
    "orderDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
    "Items": [
      {
        "facilityId": "1007",
        "facilityExternalId": "1007",
        "productId": "105",
        "identificationValue": "126"
      },
      {
        "facilityId": "1007",
        "facilityExternalId": "1007",
        "productId": "106",
        "identificationValue": "162"
      },
      {
        "facilityId": "1008",
        "facilityExternalId": "1008",
        "productId": "107",
        "identificationValue": "165"
      },
      {
        "facilityId": "1008",
        "facilityExternalId": "1008",
        "productId": "108",
        "identificationValue": "14"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to determine the grouping well. Principally need to group by `orderId`, and then should group the subobjects by the index nodes of the subarray(which start with `shipment`) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "grandTotal": "@1,orderId.&",
        "shipments": {
          "*": {
            "shipmentItems": {
              "*": {
                "*": "@1,orderId.&",
                "facility*|pro*": "@1,orderId.&3_&1.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ord*|gr*": "[#2].&",
        "*": {
          "*": "[#3].Items[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only one among the repeating components from each array
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ord*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the null components
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit** : You can use the following transformation for ***Part 2*** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "shipments": {
          "*": {
            "shipmentItems": {
              "*": {
                "Identifications": "ONE"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "grandTotal": "@1,orderId.&",
        "shipments": {
          "*": {
            "shipmentItems": {
              "*": {
                "ord*": "@1,orderId.&",
                "Identifications": {
                  "@1,facilityId": ["@2,orderId.&4_&2.facilityId", "@2,orderId.&4_&2.facilityExternalId"],
                  "productId": "@2,orderId.&4_&2.&",
                  "idValue": "@2,orderId.&4_&2.IdentificationValue"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only one among the repeating components from each array
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ord*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ord*|gr*": "[#2].&",
        "*": {
          "*": "[#3].Items[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the null components
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Just one more question, what if each map in the ShipmentItems list also contains a list, with multiple maps. And I want to get the value from one of that map based on a condition.

Comment: Updated the question,
Added the json for the question asked in the previous comment as Part 2.

Comment: It works fine if the input json is exactly the same, but what if in the Identifications list, we want the map with identificationTypeId B and not the first one always?

Comment: Will that be possible?

Comment: I am not sure about using recursivelySquashNulls in modify-overwrite-beta. What if any of the actual fields is null? I don't intend to skip the fields with null value like facilityExternalId.

Comment: Hi @janvit04 . There are some `what if`s but not a concrete example that expresses what exactly you need, can you please edit the question so as to explain it.

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan,
I have updated the desired output of Part 2. The identificationValue for 1st item is 15 now that corresponds to IdentificationTypeId D.

Comment: And just another thought, we are collecting all the items as individual maps like 0_0, 0_1 in the order map, Can we put these items in a named list like ItemsList in the intermediate json?

Comment: @janvit04 well, but the other `identificationValue`s correspond to `"IdentificationTypeId": "A"` ... eg. the logic is not clear enough.

Comment: *Can we put these items in a named list like ItemsList in the intermediate json* Of course possible, but again better to edit the question with the desired stuff to express your need for this as well @janvit04

Comment: Hi @janvit04 ...

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan,
Thanks for your reply, I had to check on IdetificationTypeId and then get its value, it will not always be the first one.

Comment: I managed to add that check and was able to get all the items inside a named map.
I actually wanted to avoid using recursivelySquashNulls, because I may have fields with value as null and didn't want them to be removed.
Thank you so much for your answer, your approach was helpful.